# How to make a child composable match parent composable's height only if the child is smaller than the parent?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a peculiar problem with Compose. I have a scrolling view, which may have either one or more children. I would need to make the content scroll if it's larger than the scroll view, but always fill the remaining height if the content is not as high as the scroll view.

The naive way I thought it would originally work was like this:

```
val scrollState = rememberScrollState()
Column(
    modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize()
        .verticalScroll(scrollState)
) {
    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight()) {
        // Content here should fill the screen and scroll if needed
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to work. While the `Column` fills the screen, the `Box` will only take as much space as its children need.

Currently I've achieved this functionality with a hack like this:

```
var contentHeight by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
var containerHeight by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
val scrollState = rememberScrollState()

Column(
    modifier.fillMaxSize()
        .onGloballyPositioned { containerHeight = it.size.height }
        .verticalScroll(scrollState)
) {
    val contentModifier = Modifier
        .onGloballyPositioned {
            if (contentHeight == 0) contentHeight = it.boundsInParent().height.toInt()
        }
        .let {
            if (contentHeight > 0 && contentHeight < containerHeight) {
                it.height(with(LocalDensity.current) {
                    containerHeight.toDp()
                }
            } else it
        }

    // The actual content
    Box(modifier = contentModifier) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

This "works", however it makes the content flash for a single frame and causes multiple recompositions. Is there a cleaner way of achieving the same result?

Comment: Have you tried adding a set height (or modifier.fillMaxHeight()) to the column along with the vertical scroll? This should automatically do what you're trying to achieve if I understood the question correctly, please correct me if not!

Comment: @ArthurKasparian Do you mean in addition to `fillMaxSize()`? That doesn't seem to do anything. If you meant setting the modifier for the content, it behaves exactly the same as without the modifier (takes as little space vertically as needed).